# Javascript ReferenceError: Observable is not defined when added Rx.js in src

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get observables to work on my html but I keep getting this error:

ReferenceError: Observable is not defined

I am using `Firefox version: 62.0`

Here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script>
     const numberObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
         observer.next(5);
         observer.next(10);
     });
    
     numberObservable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
    </script>
    <title></title> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You're missing an ending quote after `text/javascript` is that your actual code?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistype whiles writing that question. Now added

Comment: It should be `new Rx.Observable` notice the namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `Rx.Observable` instead of simply `Observable`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script>
     const numberObservable = new Rx.Observable((observer) => {
         observer.next(5);
         observer.next(10);
     });
    
     numberObservable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
    </script>
    <title></title> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `new Rx.Observable` notice the namespace.